# Help with a Poincare type inequality: Interpolation in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory

I have a bit of an an odd question with this poincare-type
inequality. I have been able to come up with something, given below,
for $k=0,l=1$ but am unsure what to do and where to go when $p=\infty$.
I wonder if you could possibly give me a hand.

Denote by $D^{k}v(\boldsymbol{x})$, $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{ 0\right\} $,
the total derivative of order k of a function $v(\boldsymbol{x})$,
e.g., for $k=1$ the gradient of $v(\boldsymbol{x})$. Let $\Omega$
be convex and be included into a ball of radius R. Let $l\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{ 0\right\} $
with $k\leq l$ and let $p\in R$ with $p\in[1,\infty)$. Assume that
$v\in W^{l,p}(\Omega)$ satisfies the following:

\begin{align*}
{{\int_{\Omega}\partial_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}v(\boldsymbol{x})\ d\boldsymbol{x}=0\,\text{for all }\left|\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right|\leq l-1,}}\\
\end{align*}

Then the following estimate holds:

\begin{align*}
\left\Vert D^{k}v\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left(\Omega\right)} & \leq CR^{l-k}\left\Vert D^{l}v\right\Vert \\
\end{align*}

Where the constant $C$ does not depend on $\Omega$ and on $v\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$.

***What I have thus far:***

Since $\Omega$ is assumed to be convex, the integral mean value theorem
can be written as follows:

\begin{align*}
{v(\boldsymbol{x})-v(\boldsymbol{y})=\int_{0}^{1}\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\cdot(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\;dt,\quad\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\in\Omega}\\
\end{align*}

integrate resp.$\boldsymbol{y}$:

\begin{align*}
{v(\boldsymbol{x})\int_{\Omega}~d\boldsymbol{y}-\int_{\Omega}v(\boldsymbol{y})~d\boldsymbol{y}=\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1}\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\cdot(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})~dt~d\boldsymbol{y}}\\
\end{align*}

From the assumption that the second integral on the left-hand side
vanishes we get:

\begin{align*}
{v(\boldsymbol{x})=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1}\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\cdot(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\ dt\ d\boldsymbol{y}}\\
\end{align*}

Take absolute values on both sides and apply Cauchy Schwarz and using
the estimate $\left\Vert \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y}\right\Vert _{2}\leq2R$:

\begin{align*}
{|v(\boldsymbol{x})|=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\left|\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1}\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\cdot(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})\ dt\ d\boldsymbol{y}\right|}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}{\leq\ \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1}|\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\cdot(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{y})|\ \ dt\ d\boldsymbol{y}}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
{\leq\,\frac{2R}{|\Omega|}\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{1}\|\nabla v(t\boldsymbol{x}+(1-t)\boldsymbol{y})\|_{2}\,\,\,dt\,\,d\boldsymbol{y}}\\
\end{align*}

From this point, I start to get a little lost. From applying Fubin, Integral Mean Value theorem and other theorems I arrive at the following:

\begin{align*}
{\int_{\Omega}|v(\boldsymbol{x})|^{p}~~d\boldsymbol{x}\leq2CR^{p}\left\Vert \nabla v\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left(\Omega\right)}^{p}}\\
\end{align*}

and from there I have no idea which is why I ask . Thank you in advance for reading this rather rambly post by me, I appreciat and solutions or help rendered greatly!

Comment: Now you could use induction in $l$ to prove for $k=l-1$. Then induction to prove it for every $k$.

Comment: Hello Daw, sorry for the incredibly delayed response. As you suggested, I have been trying the induction but have not made much progress. Perhaps, if it is not too much trouble, you could guide me through the process from 
${\int_{\Omega}|v(\boldsymbol{x})|^{p}~~d\boldsymbol{x}\leq2CR^{p}\left\Vert \nabla v\right\Vert _{L^{p}\left(\Omega\right)}^{p}}\\$ ? I fear that the more missteps I make, the more likely I will be unable to "see the wood for the trees" as it were. I do, definetly, appreciate your input though.

Comment: replace $v$ by its weak derivative in this inequality